# Style hint box when active

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

When I enter hints mode, a box appears above each link. I can style that box with

```
highlight Hint font-size: 10; border: solid white 1px; color: #00FF00; background-color: #000000; padding: 2px;
```

But the currently selected hint has a different style, which I don't like. It's got a white-ish background which makes it difficult to read the hint text. It looks like a remnant of the default active hint style:

[image: Picture]

I would expect the `HintActive` group to let me style it when the hint is active, but that actually lets me style the underlying element. So in the above picture, I could style the “Questions” box but not the box with ‘n’ in it. I also tried with the pseudoclasses `active`, `focus`, and `hover`, but they didn't seem to do anything. (So I had `highlight Hint:active <css>` and so on in my `.pentadactylrc`)

How can I style the hint box itself when it's active?

Pentadactyl version:

```
Pentadactyl 1.1 (created 2014/03/15 20:14:21) running on:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
highlight Hint[active] <css>
```

In order to prevent repeating CSS-code you may use grouping:

```
hi Hints font-size: 10; border: solid white 1px; color: #00FF00; background-color: #000000; padding: 2px;
hi -l Hints Hint
hi -l Hints Hint[active]
```

Comment: Ah, I misread that as meaning `Hint` with an optional `active` after it in the docs. This works, thanks!